# usar variable session() en todos los controladores laravel

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

hola comunidad quisiera saber si al crear una variable de `session` en un controlador en laravel
la puedo usarla en un controlador distinto en la que fue creada,
e podido usarla en el mismo controlador pero no e he podido usarla en distintos controladores

`session(['informacion' => $data]);`

y usar la en el mismo controlador es

`echo session('informacion')`

Comment: es muuuy mala idea usar variables de sesión de esa manera.

Comment: hola, y que me suguieres usar para esto, que una variable creada en controlador usarla en otro

Comment: @ManuelTrianoDeLaC.Ricaldi para resolverlo deberias poner el ¿Porque quieres hacer eso?